# Is it possible to get the width of a character when using OpenGL bitmap fonts?

Tags: python, opengl, text, fonts, width

I am trying to align my bitmap font text in my OpenGL application but I can't find anything on getting the width of each character. This is my renderText function:

```
def renderText( self, text, fontFace, position ):
    ..... (omitted code to make post shorter)
    glRasterPos2i( position[0], self.windowSize[1] - position[1] )
    glPushAttrib( GL_LIST_BIT )
    glListBase( self.fonts[ fontFace ] - 32 )
    glCallLists( text )
    glPopAttrib()
    ......
```

I create the bitmap font and use glGenList to store it.

```
    self.fonts[ fontFace ] = glGenLists( 96 )
    font = win32ui.CreateFont( fontProperties )
    font = hDisplayContext.SelectObject( font )
    wglUseFontBitmaps( displayContext, 32, 96, self.fonts[ fontFace ] )
```

Anyone know if it's possible to get the character widths or even just the final rendered text's total width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutBitmapWidth`, `glutBitmapLength` — returns the width/length of a bitmap character/string.

Python Specification:

```
glutBitmapWidth(font, character) -> None
glutBitmapLength(font, string) -> None
```

Comment: Just for the record, the link isn't working

Comment: @CíceroAugusto, thanks. Updated.